# Postgress sum on specific field and Group BY hour and objectid

Tags: postgresql, group-by, sum

I don't have to much experience with POSTGRESS SQL
I have `datatable` with the following fields:

```
id  timestamp            value   sensor
1   2020-10-10 14:10:18   1.4     1
2   2020-10-10 14:40:15   1.1     1
3   2020-10-10 15:40:12   0.1     2
4   2020-10-10 15:50:01   2.0     2
5   2020-10-11 15:50:01   1.2     3
```

I want to  get a result per sensor with sum {value} per hour like:

```
timestamp            value   sensor
2020-10-10 14:00:00   2.5     1
2020-10-10 15:00:00   2.1     2
2020-10-11 15:00:01   1.2     3
```

I tried this:

```
SELECT sensor, timestamp, sum(value) FROM datatable ORDER BY timestamp  GROUP BY date_part('hour', timestamp),sensor
```

> it rise me error "timestamp" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be
> used in an aggregate function

**How I should build this query?**

Answer (score 1):

you can try to use [`date_trunc`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC) function, in addition, you might use `GROUP BY` before then `ORDER BY`

> date_trunc(field, source [, time_zone ])

```
SELECT date_trunc('hour', "timestamp"),sum(value) ,sensor
FROM datatable 
GROUP BY date_trunc('hour', "timestamp"),sensor
ORDER BY 1
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=aca9cc579eafb92ed746b4006c011d62)